# Video from webcam showing black screen in kazam screen recorder

Tags: video, webcam, kazam

I am using

`Ubuntu 16.04` and for screen recording `kazam 1.5.3`

I am trying to use `video from webcam` option available in `kazam`.

But `video from webcam` is not working. when i check the `video from webcam` option it is showing black box rather than webcam.

Where is the problem. and how can i get rid of this.

Here is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that webcam is working normally? Do you have video from it in `guvcview`?

Comment: I think the webcam is working properly. as 
```Cheese webcam booth``` in ubuntu is working nice.

and can you please tell me what is ```guvcview```

Comment: [Guvcview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guvcview) is just another webcam application like [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese). It can help to test webcam.

Comment: btw, web cam work nice and perfect in skype too.

Comment: @N0rbert did you get any solution please.

Comment: I have never used kazam, I can't help with it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to drag and drop recording on Google Chrome to check if the recording is actually black or not. In my case in VLC Medi player was playing recording as black screen but it played like a normal video in Google Chrome.

Comment: So any idea why VLC isn't working in this case?

Comment: I had a similar problem with the screen being black but with Totem Video Player. The same video worked fine with VLC!